# How to change attribute of Html.Beginform() on form Submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have this so far:

```
 <% foreach (Object object in Collection)
 {
     u<% using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "Controller", new { FU = "bar" }, FormMethod.Post, new { ID = "MyID"}))
      {%>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      <%}
 } %>

 $('#MyID').submit(function() {
     var url = Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName");
     var fu = "newValueOfFU"; // New value for FU
     $('#MyID').prop('action', url + "?FU=" + fu);
 });
```

I want to change the value of FU with the value from jQuery

Comment: Can you provide the html generated by this code?

Comment: You're using the wrong overload on that "Problem 2" Html.BeginForm() method. The 'onsubmit' attribute is part of the RouteValues currently, not the object html attributes.

Comment: @Graham ah someone else that can see the problem. +1.

Comment: If i use the overloads that i am supposed to, i can`t reach FU in the controller

Comment: There are multiple overloads, use whichever is valid.  Just ensure you do not confuse `RouteValues` with `HtmlAttributeValues`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplified Answer.

You are using the incorrect overload. See the overloads list on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) for an idea of which to use.

Your current overloads expects routing information as the 3rd parameter.  Any values that you provide will be matched against the routes defined for the site.  If any parameters do not match it, they will be simply added as get parameters.

What you are trying to achieve is to assign an `ID` or another attribute to the form.  This is done using an overload which allows for html attributes to be defined (see [Overload on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492714%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). eg,

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.POST, new {ID = "MyID"}))
```

**Note**: The order of parameters is **Different**.

Simply look at the html generated and you will get an idea of what is happening.

// Update

Use this

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new {FU="bar"}, FormMethod.POST, new {ID = "MyID", onsubmit="return sayHello()"}))
```

This will generate html similar to

```
 <form action="/Controller/Action?FU=Hello" method="post" id="MyID" onsumbit="return sayHello()">
```

and combined with script

```
<script>
    function sayHello()
    {
        alert("Hello");
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

will give you alert, as well as sending `FU` to controller.

// Update
This is how you can update the action attribute of a form.

```
<script>
  $('#MyID').submit(function() {
      var url = @Url.Action("Action","Controller");
      var fu = "newValueOfFU"; // New value for FU
      $('#MyID').prop('action', url + "?FU=" + fu;
      return true;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @user2047644 updated. You are not using the correct overload, see the link for the full list.

Comment: I can reach the controller and the specified action and i can print the FU. This is not the problem.

Comment: @user2047644 Like I have tried to point out, the HTML generated is not what you are expecting.  Edit your question to include the html and it will be obvious.

Comment: If i use the overloads that you proposed, i can`t reach FU in the controller

Comment: @user2047644 There are a whole bunch of overloads.  The answer illustrates the use of a different overload.  Use whichever is appropriate to your needs.

Comment: So the new HTML is posted in the question

Comment: @user2047644 I have updated for you the complete overload that *should* work.  It will send `FU` to the server, and apply `id` attribute.

Comment: Ok that worked perfect. So now how to change the value of FU?

Comment: @user2047644 basic overview of how to change action attribute. Expand/Adapt to your needs.

Comment: The jQuery function that you provide in the Update does not change the  FU Value

Comment: Change the "Action" attribute of the form in the jQuery function. Once the script exits, the post will fire to whatever the modified "Action" of the form is.

Comment: I changed Action and controller with my mvc names... Still nothing... I can reach my action in the controller but FU is not changed

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following jQuery code

```
$('form').submit(function(){
   $(this).attr('ID', newVal);
});
```

Or you can assign an ID to your form like

```
using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "myForm", FU = "Hello" }))
```

and use it to hook an event on submit

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(){
       $(this).attr('ID', newVal);
    });
```

Comment: I think your `BeginForm` method is incorrect. See my answer for correct overload.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an onSubmit event handler in the HTMLAttributes and change the ID in that.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "Controller", new { ID = "Hello", onsubmit = "return changeID();"  }, FormMethod.Post))
           {%>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <%} %>
```

And add the following script somewhere in your page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeID() {
           document.getElementById('Hello').id  = 'Your_New_Value';         

           return true;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#formID').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
         $('#yourOtherID').attr(newValue);
    });

});
</script>
```